# How does WordPress format the url on a 301 when a trailing slash is missing?

Tags: redirect, proxy

I have a reverse proxy in front of WP that maps some requests on the root `example.com/page1/` over to the wp install `wp.example.com/page1/`.

This works fine until the url is missing the trailing slash.  WP returns a `301` that is the absolute url `wp.example.com/page1`.  I am trying to figure out how that URL is created, and hopefully change it.

I updated `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` in WP -> Settings, but that doesn't change the response from what I saw.  Looking at the `wp_posts` table the `guid` has an absolute url, maybe that is used with a transform to the pretty url?

Can I just globally set the redirect URLS for WP, preferably to being relative, without breaking all the paths for the assets uploaded to `wp_content`?

Comment: If you mean `wp.example.com/page1` redirects to `wp.example.com/page1/`, then it's likely done via [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) which among other things, avoids duplicate content penalty since the request URLs are identical and it's common for WordPress sites to use the URL with trailing slash than without it.

Comment: `example.com/page1` redirects to `wp.example.com/page1/`

Comment: @blu - curious if you ever got this resolved? running into the exact same issue with a reverse proxy.